# What is the cause of the strange squares on the map in the picture

Tags: openlayers

So this problem appears when I try to zoom on the map, in some places some kind of rectangular areas appear or the layers act strange, like on the map shown in the picture.The area that is in the red rectangle in particular.[image]

The green is getting cut off or smt and this only happens when I zoom. Any help on how to deal with  this problem is appreciated and I can provide the code I am using if this problem is not solvable only with the image.

Comment: The problem is due to inconsistencies in the OpenStreetMap tiles and can also be seen here https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=12/41.5171/24.7944  There is nothing your application can do about that if you wish to use the standard OSM tiles.

Comment: @Mike any other maps i can use or any way to remove the green at all for the application I only need the water to be visible the other parts don't  matter that much it just bugs me out when the squares apear

Comment: You could try another map provider such as Bing https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/bing-maps.html or Here https://openlayers.org/en/main/examples/here-maps.html but like most services to use these you must get an API key and they have a monthly usage limit for the free service.  If you need the labels in Bulgarian specify `culture: 'bg'` in the Bing options and add `&lg=mul` to the Here url.